# I am working on target follow up tool on Excel. Issue related to conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

The scenario is:

Cell T2 has target date entered already.
Next cell U2 is blank and it is where actual date is to be entered when action is taken.
Target is 5 days.

**If the date entered in U2 is with in 5 days of the date in T2, then U2 cell should be green. If the date entered is past 5 days of the date in T2, then the color in U2 should turn red.**

Thank you for your help..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Click on cell U2 and select Conditional formatting > New Rule > 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format' and use a formula like the one below (the ISNUMBER(U2) condition prevents the application from interpreting a blank cell as the date with serial number of 0 and making the first condition true). Set the cell fill format for that condition to green.

`=AND(($U$2-$T$2)<=5,ISNUMBER($U$2))`

You'd then add a second formula for the red condition.